# When I run the code, it returns 1 not the right number of repeated values in the list "list of int"

Tags: list, ml

I want to get an int that indicates the number of repeated values in the list of int

```
 fun iretate_list (fx : int list, tn : int) = 
   if null fx 
   then [] 
   else
         let val count = 0
         in
             if hd fx = tn then count + 1 :: [] else iretate_list(tl fx, tn)
         end
```

Comment: Explain what is this, and what do you want it to be.

Comment: I want to get an int that indicates the number of repeated values in the in list

Comment: Dont write it in comment write in your post

Comment: StackOverflow is a terrible debugger! https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

If the element is found, the result is `[count + 1]`, and `count + 1` is `0 + 1`, which is `1`, so ...

The result should be an `int`, not a list, so start with changing your base case to `0` – not `[]`.
You should also not stop when you find a match, but recurse and do something with the result.

```
fun iterate_list ([], tn) = 0
  | iterate_list (x::xs, tn) = if x = tn
                               then <something involving recursion on xs>
                               else iterate_list (xs, tn)
```

Some parts left as an exercise.